# How to Dial Phone Number With "#" Symbol on a Mobile Browser

Tags: android, html, mobile, hyperlink

We are trying to get a phone number containing the "#" symbol to auto dial when accessed via a link in a mobile browser.  Seems to work for BlackBerry OS, but not working for Android.  We are aware that iOS does NOT work with the # symbol for security reasons, but what about Android- why no dice there?

Comment: Which link format are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `%23` URL Encoding to replace the "#"?